# setParent(this) with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic Element class which contains elements of the same class. Based on that I would then create concrete classes like

```
Boxes extends Element<Boxes>
```

The point I don't get is the

```
setParent(this);
```

Why do I need to cast it

```
setParent((C) this);
```

(and suppress type casting warnings)? Obviously I am missing something...
How would you change the class to have no casting and no warnings?
I would argue that "this" is a Element object (at minimum) and C as well.

```
public class Element<C extends Element<C>> {
List<C> children;
C parent = null;

public Element() {
}

void setChildren(List<C> children) {
    this.children = children;
    for (C c : children) {
        c.setParent((C) this); // warning, without the cast: error
    }
}

void setParent(C parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is because this is of type `Element<C>` and not of type `C`.

Comment: Because it's wrong. `parent` is a `C`, and `this` is an `Element<C>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because `this` is of type `Element<C>` and not of type `C`.

The following would work:

```
public class Element<C extends Element<C>> {
    List<C> children;
    Element<C> parent = null;

    public Element() {
    }

    void setChildren(List<C> children) {
        this.children = children;
        for (C c : children) {
            c.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    void setParent(Element<C> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Btw, IDEs are pretty good explaining why you get such errors.

Answer (score 4):

Because nothing guarantees that `this` is of type C.

For example, you could create an object this way:

```
Element<Boxes> e = new Element<>();
```

or this way:

```
class Container extends Element<Boxes> {}
...
Container c = new Container();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `protected abstract C self()` method to `Element<C>` class and use it instead of `(C) this`:

```
public abstract class Element<C extends Element<C>> {
    List<C> children;
    C parent = null;

    protected abstract C self();

    void setChildren(List<C> children) {
        this.children = children;
        for (C c : children) {
            c.setParent(self());
        }
    }

    void setParent(C parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Now when you extend `Element<C>` you can implement `self()` just by returning `this`:

```
public class Boxes extends Element<Boxes> {
    @Override
    protected Boxes self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

This is a pretty popular design. You can see it, for example, if you [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) builders which are generated with Lombok [`@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) annotation:

```
public class Example {
    private final int someField;

    protected Example(ExampleBuilder<?, ?> b) {
        this.someField = b.someField;
    }

    public static ExampleBuilder<?, ?> builder() {
        return new ExampleBuilderImpl();
    }

    public static abstract class ExampleBuilder<C extends Example, B extends ExampleBuilder<C, B>> {
        private int someField;

        public B someField(int someField) {
            this.someField = someField;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract B self();

        public abstract C build();

        public String toString() {
            return "Example.ExampleBuilder(someField=" + this.someField + ")";
        }
    }

    private static final class ExampleBuilderImpl extends ExampleBuilder<Example, ExampleBuilderImpl> {
        protected Example.ExampleBuilderImpl self() {
            return this;
        }

        public Example build() {
            return new Example(this);
        }
    }
}
```